# How to compute Lucas Kanade flow?

Tags: c++, opencv, opticalflow

I am currently working on a project of object tracking and have used C++ and OpenCV. I have successfully used Farneback dense optical flow to implement segmentation methods such as k means (using the displacement in each frame). Now I want to do the same thing with Lucas Kanade sparse method. But the output of this function is:

> nextPts – output vector of 2D points (with single-precision floating-point coordinates) containing the calculated new positions of input features in the second image; when OPTFLOW_USE_INITIAL_FLOW flag is passed, the vector must have the same size as in the input.

(as stated by the official site)

My question is **How I am going to get the result to a Mat flow?** for example I have so far tried:

```
    // Implement Lucas Kanade algorithm
    cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK(frame1_1C, frame2_1C, pyramid1, pyramid2,
                           frame1_features, frame2_features, number_of_features,
                           optical_flow_window, 5, optical_flow_found_feature,
                           optical_flow_feature_error, optical_flow_termination_criteria,
                           0);
    // Calculate each feature point's coordinates in every frame
    CvPoint p, q;
    p.x = (int)frame1_features[i].x;
    p.y = (int)frame1_features[i].y;

    q.x = (int)frame2_features[i].x;
    q.y = (int)frame2_features[i].y;
    // Creating the arrows for imshow

    angle      = atan2((double)p.y - q.y, (double)p.x - q.x);
    hypotenuse = sqrt(square(p.y - q.y) + square(p.x - q.x));

    /* Here we lengthen the arrow by a factor of three. */

    q.x = (int)(p.x - 3 * hypotenuse * cos(angle));
    q.y = (int)(p.y - 3 * hypotenuse * sin(angle));

    cvLine(frame1, p, q, line_color, line_thickness, CV_AA, 0);

    p.x = (int)(q.x + 9 * cos(angle + pi / 4));
    p.y = (int)(q.y + 9 * sin(angle + pi / 4));
    cvLine(frame1, p, q, line_color, line_thickness, CV_AA, 0);
    p.x = (int)(q.x + 9 * cos(angle - pi / 4));
    p.y = (int)(q.y + 9 * sin(angle - pi / 4));
    cvLine(frame1, p, q, line_color, line_thickness, CV_AA, 0);

    allocateOnDemand(&framenew, frame_size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    cvConvertImage(frame1, framenew, CV_CVTIMG_FLIP);

    cvShowImage("Optical Flow", framenew);
```

This is the optical flow presentation. Any ideas on how I should get a Mat flow similar to the result of the Farneback optical flow?

(http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowfarneback )

**UPDATE**: Very good answer. But now I have problems with showing the kmeans image. With farneback I used:

```
    cv::kmeans(m, K, bestLabels,
               TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0),
               3, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
    int colors[K];
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        colors[i] = 255 / (i + 1);
    }

    namedWindow("Kmeans", WINDOW_NORMAL);

    Mat clustered = Mat(flow.rows, flow.cols, CV_32F);

    for (int i = 0; i < flow.cols * flow.rows; i++) {
        clustered.at<float>(i / flow.cols, i % flow.cols) =
            (float)(colors[bestLabels.at<int>(0, i)]);
    }
    clustered.convertTo(clustered, CV_8U);
    imshow("Kmeans", clustered);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: not sure about the types used by dense opzical flow,but prob. sth. like this: for each point in f1features and corrdsponding pt in f2features: map.at<cv::Vec2f>(point) = cv::Vec2f(f2feature.x-f1feature.x, f2feature.y-f1feature.y). Set all other points to a value the represents "unknown - could not extract flow for that pixel"

Comment: What do you mean by yuor last sentence ? Can you explain a bit further?  Thank you I was thinking of somethink similar !

Comment: lucas kanade computes a very sparse flow. So there will be many points in your map-as-in-dense-flow for which you dont have a flow information. You must decide what kind of values you will put to those pixel.

Comment: So map is a Mat , what is point ?

Comment: the result of your lucas kanade. pixelor subpixel positions.

Comment: I am not sure why you are using the c functions of opencv instead of the c++ ones if you are programming in c++. Also, you said that you want to use the **Sparse** version of the Lukas Kanade, but I see that you want to obtain a Dense Matrix like Farneback. The Sparse method will take a set points and calculates the optical flow of this point and estimate the position. In summary it will be a tracker of 2D points based on optical flow. You do an image similar to it, but it will have only the information of the sparse points.

Comment: @Micka So in my program : map.at<cv::Vec2f>(frame2_features[i]) = cv::Vec2f(q.x-p.x, q.y-p.y); ??

Comment: @api55 Which are not c++ functions ? I actually want to use k means based on optical flow. I have already done it in a program with dense optical flow , so I thought I will try it here too. If there is another way of doing it , any ideas are welcome of course ! So here I have a vector of the coordinates of the extracted features in the new frame . How can i use it in k means ? I guess I want the difference of the previous frame as suggested by Micka .

Comment: Can you provide two sample images and draw/mark assumed cluster?

Comment: @george_t I added a possible answer to your question, and the function names that start with cv are usually opencv c version. In the documentation you can see that they have `C++: void calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` and `C: void cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK`. Also, I have used KMeans directly to the 2D new points, but I am not sure if you want to cluster similar points in the new image (close ones) or cluster the ones that have similar difference between the two images, if it is the later, just a vector of cv::Point2f with the difference will work

Comment: @api55 I want to cluster moving objects (e.g. cars ) at first. So I am mainly interested in the displacement. Then I might also use brightness for example as information .

Comment: @george_t well, you can always use a `std::vector<cv::Vec2f>` in here you can put the displacement of each point. Also it is possible to use `cv::Vec4f`if you want the kmeans to take in account the initial position or final position of the object. Or even `cv::Vec5f` if you want to include the intensity in the calculations. I will update my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get an image like the Farneback algorithm you must first understand what is the output.

In OpenCV docs you have:

`prev(y,x) ~ next(y + flow(y,x)[1], x +flow(y,x)[0])`

So, it is a matrix with the displacements between image 1 and 2. Assuming that the points that you are not calculating will be without movement 0,0;  you can simulate this, you only have to put for each of the points `(x,y)` having the new position `(x', y')`:

```
cv::Mat LKFlowMatrix(img.rows, img.cols, CV_32FC2, cv::Scalar(0,0));
LKFlowMatrix.at<cv::Vec2f>(y,x) = cv::Vec2f(x-x', y-y') ;
```

Also, don't forget to filter the "not found points" with the status = 0

By The Way, your functions are not the opencv c++ version of it:

`cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK` should be `cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback` in c++
`cvShowImage`should be `cv::imshow`in c++
and so on

** UPDATE **

Since you need is an input for kmeans (I suppose that is the OpenCV version), and you want to use only the Sparse Points, then you can do something like this:

```
cv::Mat prevImg, nextImg;
// load your images

std::vector<cv:Point2f> initial_points, new_points;
// fill the initial points vector 

std::vector<uchar> status;
std::vector<float> error;

cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevImage, nextImage, initial_points, new_points, status, errors);

std::vector<cv::Vec2f> vectorForKMeans;
for(size_t t = 0; t < status.size(); t++){
  if(status[t] != 0)
    vectorForKmeans.push_back(cv::Vec2f(initial_points[i] - new_points[i]));
}

// Do kmeans to vectorForKMeans
```

Comment: @george_t That should be in another question, it is related but it is not the topic of the question... anyhow, you can pass to kmeans a vector of `Vec2f` or of points or a mat. Also, the output can be a mat, vector of labels (int if i remember correctly). and `labels[i]` will correspond to `vectorForKmeans[i]` so you can use something like `colors[labels[i]]` to color the point i

Comment: @api55 if instead of the lucas kanade algorithm the farneback algorithm is used, how is it possible to perform the k means on this data?

Comment: @MMahdiChamseddine in the question, the last update shows what the OP used when he had farneback... kmeans accepts a cv::Mat so you can pass a dense result as well